# Passing text file lines as separated args to commands?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

Hi I've been trying to figuring out how to simply pass an file.txt with multiple lines into a bash script args to run as a command. Not sure I should be doing while loops?

So the text file just contains something like about.

```
ip_addr1,foo:bar
ip_addr2,foo2:bar2
user@ip_addr3,foo3:bar3
```

And I just want a bash script to take the content from that file and use it as a bash script, as an example like

```
ssh ip_addr1 'echo "foo:bar" > /root/text.txt' 
ssh ip_addr2 'echo "foo2:bar2" > /root/text.txt'
ssh user@ip_addr3 'echo "foo3:bar3" > /root/text.txt'
```

So the script will execute depending on how many lines the text file has..

Comment: Can you please clarify what specifically you need help with? Reading a line from a file? Seperating the tokens? Forming the command? etc. Have you made any attempt or have any ideas?

Comment: Hi, @kaylum I basically tried to use a text file in a bash script, whereas the text file will be imported into linux command that runs in the bash script. The text file contains info that's separated with a comma. I've tried a couple of attempts but no success.

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate through the lines of the file with the bash `read` command as suggested from the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521462/looping-through-the-content-of-a-file-in-bash).

```
while read -r line
do
  # $line will be a variable which contains one line of the input file
done < your_file.txt
```

You can use `read` again with the `IFS` variable to get the content from each line split by the `IFS` variable, as suggested by answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10520623/how-to-split-one-string-into-multiple-variables-in-bash-shell).

```
while read -r line
do
  # $line will be a variable which contains one line of the input file
  IFS=, read -r ip_addr data <<< "$line"
  # now, $ip_addr stores the stuff to the left of the comma, and $data stores the stuff to the right
done < your_file.txt
```

From there, you can run whatever command you want to run with the new variables.

```
while read -r line
do
  # $line will be a variable which contains one line of the input file
  IFS=, read -r ip_addr data <<< "$line"
  # now, $ip_addr stores the stuff to the left of the comma, and $data stores the stuff to the right
  ssh "$ip_addr" "echo \"${data}\" >  /root/text.txt"
done < your_file.txt
```

If you don't need the `$line` variable, you can use a single `read` command.

```
while IFS=, read -r ip_addr data
do
  # now, $ip_addr stores the stuff to the left of the comma, and $data stores the stuff to the right
  ssh "$ip_addr" "echo \"${data}\" >  /root/text.txt"
done < your_file.txt
```

Comment: See also [Understanding "IFS= read -r line"](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/209123) (`read line` does not read a line).

Comment: Hi there this perfectly works, though how would I made it read on to the next line since it only execute once from the first line?

Comment: Why do you `read` each line _twice_?  Couldn't you just use `IFS=, read -r ip_addr data` from the start?

Comment: Well trying that will only read the first line, it doesn't continue till the ending trail.

Comment: @Kusalananda you're right, you can just `read` once. If any further processing needs to be done on the line as a whole, it may be useful to have it as a variable. I'll edit the answer with your suggestion though.

Comment: @Ryan what do you mean by making it read on to the next line? There is a loop that runs for each line.

Answer (score 0):

Transform the input file to a shell script using `sed`

```
$ sed -e "s|\([^,]*\),\(.*\)|ssh -n \"\1\" 'echo \"\2\" >/root/text.txt'|" file
ssh -n "ip_addr1" 'echo "foo:bar" >/root/text.txt'
ssh -n "ip_addr2" 'echo "foo2:bar2" >/root/text.txt'
ssh -n "user@ip_addr3" 'echo "foo3:bar3" >/root/text.txt'
```

or `awk`,

```
$ awk -F ',' '{ printf("ssh -n \"%s\" '\''echo \"%s\" >/root/text.txt'\''\n", $1, $2) }' file
ssh -n "ip_addr1" 'echo "foo:bar" >/root/text.txt'
ssh -n "ip_addr2" 'echo "foo2:bar2" >/root/text.txt'
ssh -n "user@ip_addr3" 'echo "foo3:bar3" >/root/text.txt'
```

Then save the output of either of those to a file using a redirection and run it with `sh`.  This way you additionally have a record of exactly what commands were executed.

Alternatively, you could execute the output of either command with

```sh
...either command above... | sh -s
```

Comment: Hmm given the example with the txt file, I might have more then 50-60 lines of credentials. So wouldn't it be better to have it loop+while?

Comment: @Ryan If you want something that is better for running commands on a set of machines, or for distributing data to a cluster, look at Ansible or similar software. Personally, I would create all `text.txt` files on a central admin server, and then distribute them from there rather than assuming that `echo` would preserve the strings literally.

Comment: Well the point of the bash script is just to simply execute all the same commands with different credentials, without looking into software where I don't have to spend time playing around with newer repo as an example.